# If a function A is called only called by another function B, will GCC automatically puts that function A into funtion B as a part of B's code?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

For example:

There's a function A:

```
void functionA();
```

and a function B:

```
void functionB() {
    functionA();
}
```

if funcionA is only called by functionB in the whole project, will GCC(or other compiler) automatically put functionA into functionB as part of functionB's code?

Or should I use -O3 to force enable the inline feature in GCC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC may inline the function based on the following rules:
With -O1, if functionA is static and is only called once.
With -O2, if the body is expected to be smaller than the function call code.
With -O3, gcc will consider inlining all functions.
Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html